# Output Matrix Block with Element API Plugin

Tags: matrix, json

Below is my code to output the news entires under the "news" section of my site using the Element API. My question is how do I output the matrix block with a block type of "text" with a field called "blockText"?

https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/qcuestions/13118/how-do-you-use-the-element-api-plugin-to-output-matrix-blocks-for-an-entry

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'api/entries' => [
            'elementType' => 'Entry',
            'criteria' => ['section' => 'news'],
            'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
              // Check to see if there are any images
              $featuredImage = $entry->featuredImage->first();
              $bodyBlocks = [];
               foreach ($entry->bodyEnhanced as $block) {

                   switch ($block->type->handle) {
                       case 'text':
                           $bodyBlocks[] = [
                            //'text' => $block->type->attributeConfigs,
                            'content' => $block->type->bodyText
                           ];
                       break;
                   }
               }

                return [
                    'id' => $entry->id,
                    'url' => $entry->url,
                    'postDate' => $entry->postDate,
                    'title' => $entry->title,
                    'excerpt' => !empty($entry->excerpt) ? $entry->excerpt : false,
                    'image' =>   !empty($featuredImage) ? $featuredImage->url : false,
                    'body' => $bodyBlocks,
                ];
            }
        ],
    ],
];
```

[image: screenshot of matrix block]

This is the only line that is breaking my JSON. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
'content' => $block->type->bodyText
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to call

```
$block->text->getParsedContent()
```

or another method of [RichTextData](https://craftcms.com/classreference/fieldtypes/RichTextData) Model